# Why angular doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs

What is wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='SOO'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller='someController'>
        <p>{{someData}}</p>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var app = angular.module('SOO', ['ngRoute']);
            app.controller('someController', function($scope){
                $scope.someData = 'Ok, all good!';
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And error message in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error…s.org%2F1.3.0-beta.7%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20E...<omitted>...2) angular.js:36
```

But examples from the official site are working normal. I can't see the serious difference.

Comment: Please change the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
var app = app.module('SOO', ['ngRoute']);
```

To:

```
var app = angular.module('SOO', ['ngRoute']);
```

And remove the jQuery document ready handler that is wrapping your code:

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('SOO', ['ngRoute']);
  app.controller('someController', function($scope){
    $scope.someData = 'Ok, all good!';
  });
</script>
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#automatic-initialization):

> Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event or when
>   the angular.js script is evaluated if at that time document.readyState
>   is set to 'complete'. At this point Angular looks for the ng-app
>   directive which designates your application root.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove Jquery statement $(function(){}), then everything works fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='SOO'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller='someController'>
      <p>{{someData}}</p>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>      
      var app = angular.module('SOO', ['ngRoute']);
      app.controller('someController', function($scope){
       $scope.someData = 'Ok, all good!';
      });        
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```